# Reference for generalized linear mixed models using Laplace approximation

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, references, approximation, laplace-approximation

I'm fitting a generalized linear mixed model in R using the Laplace approximation. I'm looking for a reference for the Laplace approximation used for that, or a reference regarding the comparison between the PQL and Laplace methods for fitting generalized linear mixed models.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some papers:

Breslow and Clayton, 1993:  [*Approximate Inference in Generalized Linear Mixed Models*](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~ruben/papers/BreslowClaytonPQLpaper.pdf).

Tierney and Kadane, 1986: [*Accurate Approximations for Posterior Moments and Marginal Densities*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10-702/laplace.pdf).

Breslow, 2003: [*Whither PQL?*](http://www.bepress.com/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1015&context=uwbiostat).

Tuerlinckx, et al. 2006: [*Statistical Inference in generalized linear mixed models: A review*](http://ppw.kuleuven.be/okp/_pdf/Tuerlickx2006SIIGL.pdf).

Wolfinger, 1993: [*Laplace's approximation for nonlinear mixed models*](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/80/4/791.abstract).

Vonesh, 1996: [*A Note on the Use of Laplace's Approximation for Nonlinear Mixed-Effects Models*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2337614).

Comment: See also the `INLA` package and papers by Havard Rue.

Comment: Is there any literature on Laplace approximation for discrete distribution?